# ftp: Login to server, auto-change remote dir, then bring user input?

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I'm using "ftp" with the login credentials in .netrc for auto-login to a remote FTP server.
The thing is that I always need to "cd" to my remote working dir manually each time I log in.
Is there any way to "cd" automatically on connection, and then bring the user input after the directory was changed?

Comment: various GUI based ftp clients support an auto-cd feature; for a cmd-line ftp client w/o the feature, one idea is automating login+cd with an `expect` script along with "interact" built-in command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to defined a macro named `init`

Extract from `man netrc`

```
 macdef name
           Define a macro.  This token functions like the ftp macdef command functions.  
           A macro is defined with the specified name;
           its contents begin with the next .netrc line and continue until a null line
           (consecutive new-line characters) is encountered.  If a macro named
           init is defined, it is automatically executed as the last step in
           the auto-login process.
```

A example of `.netrc` with a **init** macro :

```
machine 192.168.19.5
login  theusername
password theSECRETpassword
macdef init
pwd
!pwd
lcd /tmp
cd /tmp
pwd
!pwd

machine 192.168.19.6
../..
```

Comment: `macdef init` then `cd path/to/work/dir` worked perfectly! Thanks a lot.